# Form data to a CSV

Tags: php, fopen, export-to-csv, postdata

I wrote this tid-bit of code as an attempt to grab the data from a timesheet form I created with contact form 7, save that data into a csv formatted the way I want, and then send that over to email specified in the "Mail" section of the Contact Form. Unfortunately, I've ran into 2 problems that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Can't seem to get save the CSV document into the directory I defined. Or save at all for that matter. Here's my code:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'add_form_as_attachment', 10, 1 ); 

function add_form_as_attachment(&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $pay_rate = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'pay-rate', true );

    $list = array (
        array( 'Employee Name:', $current_user->display_name),
        array( 'Selected Week:', $pay_rate),
        array( 'Weekday', 'Job Number', 'Labor Desc', 'Labor Code', 'Total Hours', 'Break Hours'),
        array(
            'Sunday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-sun'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-sun'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-sun'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-sun'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-sun']
        ),array(
            'Monday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-mon'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-mon'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-mon'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-mon'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-mon']
        ),array(
            'Tuesday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-tue'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-tue'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-tue'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-tue'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-tue']
        ),array(
            'Wednesday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-wed'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-wed'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-wed'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-wed'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-wed']
        ),array(
            'Thursday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-thu'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-thu'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-thu'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-thu'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-thu']
        ),array(
            'Friday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-fri'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-fri'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-fri'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-fri'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-fri']
        ),array(
            'Saturday',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['job-number-sat'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-desc-sat'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['labor-code-sat'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['total-hours-sat'],
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['break-hours-sat']
        ),array(
            'Travel Mileage (Miles):',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['mileage'],
            'Travel Mileage (MPG):',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['mpg']
        ),array(
            'Remarks:',
            $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['remarks']
        )
    );

    $debug_echo = 'Target Directory: ' . $target_directory . '\n\n';
    $debug_echo .= 'WPCF7 Upload Directory: ' . wpcf7_upload_tmp_dir() . '\n\n';
    $debug_echo .= 'Real Path: ' . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\n\n';
    $debug_echo .= 'Target Directory Permissions: ' . substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms( $target_directory )), -4);

    $target_directory = '/nas/content/live/lovettmechanic/wp-content/uploads/timesheets/timesheet.csv';

    $fp = fopen( $target_directory , 'w');
    debug_to_console( $debug_echo );


    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);

}

function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
        $output = implode( ',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}
```

Any help will be definitely appreciated. Been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this one out for a while.

==EDIT==
I edited the question to show that perhaps the function isn't firing in the first place. Or at least the `echo` command in the `debug_to_console()` function isn't. Then again it must be firing, because I'll get a http 500 error if there's a syntax error. But the `debug_to_console()` function isn't behaving as expected. I think that may help figure out the issue.

Comment: I was playing with SQLite today and noticed a ".separator csv" command. Maybe write code for PHP to create a SQLite .db and save that way.

Comment: @takintoolong The reason why I want to save it as a csv, is so that I can grab the file and send it as an attachment in an email with the Contact Form 7 mail function.

Comment: $fp = fopen( $target_directory , 'w'); returns false when it fails.         fputcsv($fp, $fields); then tries to put to false... 500 error could this be the case?

Comment: @MartenvanMiddelaar Not getting a 500 error. I was just saying that I know the function is executing because I'll get a 500 error if threre's a syntax error.

Comment: Anyone have any insight on this, I'm still lost. Been trying different levels or research for a few days here.

Comment: fwrite()? It looks like you are just outputting to the console? Idk I am new